# Solution to tensor/matrix equation

Tags: matrix-equations, tensors

I need to find a real, symmetric matrix, $A$, that satisfies:

$\sum_{i,j} c_i c_j A_{ki}A_{jl} = A_{lk}$

I believe this is an equation of the form:

$c^T B c = A$, where $c$ is $\mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$, $B$ is $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N \times N \times N}$ and $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$

What, if any, is the method of solution to this problem, preferably analytic? I don't mind minimal additional assumptions to simplify it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation can be written in matrix form (assuming $A=A^T$) as $ACC^TA=A$. Due to the rank bounds for products we have
$$
\text{rank}A=\text{rank}ACC^TA\le\text{rank}C=1,
$$
so the matrix has rank one or zero. $A=0$ is a trivial solution, so let's consider rank is one, i.e. $A=BB^T$ for some vector $B$. Set it into the equation
$$
BB^T=BB^TCC^TBB^T\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad (B^TC)^2=1\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad B^TC=\pm 1.
$$
Thus, all possible symmetric solutions are $A=0$ and $A=BB^T$ where $B^TC=\pm 1$.

Comment: The first line nailed it.